# AngularJS $crypto and ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module('App',['mdo-angular-cryptography']);

app.controller('AtvdCtrl', function($scope, $crypto, PassWD, $http){  

    $scope.frInEtAc = ''; //edited 

    $scope.decriptar = function(dado){        
        return $crypto.decrypt(dado, $scope.PassWD.senha);
    }; 

    //edited
    $scope.frnt = [];
    $http.get('myURL')
    .success(function(retorno){
         $scope.frnt = retorno;
    })
    .error(function(erro){
         console.log(erro); 
    });

    $scope.Atvd = [];
    $http.get('myURL')
    .success(function(retorno){
         $scope.Atvd = retorno;
    })
    .error(function(erro){
         console.log(erro); 
    });

    $scope.inicEtgaAc = [];
    $scope.acharInicAc = function(cd){
    $http.get('myURL' + cd)
    .success(function(returnoI){
        $scope.inicEtgaAc = returnIncEntregaA;
    })
    .error(function(erro){
        console.log(erro);
    });
};
};

});
```

HTML Code:

```
<select id="nmFrInEtAc" ng-options="opt.cdFrnt as (decriptar(opt.nmFrnt) | uppercase) for opt in frnt" ng-model="frInEtAc" ng-change='acharInicAc(frInEtAc)' ng-required='true'>
       <option style="display:none" value=""></option>
</select>
```

Especifically in ng-options my function doesn't work.

I have all the depencencies especified here: https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography

It does work in here:

```
<div ng-repeat='atvd in Atvd>
    <span ng-bind='decriptar(atvd.nmAtvd)'/>
<div/>
```

Comment: this code doesn't make any sense.  There isn't anything in that HTML that even vaguely matches up with the posted JavaScript.  Literally **all** of your variable and function names either don't exist or aren't being shown here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write all the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to iterate over a variable that doesn't exist. Your HTML code is iterating with `for opt in frnt` but your controller never actually sets a value for `$scope.frnt`.